# What supplements/diet/activities can I do to improve mental function?

Tags: brain

I am currently going through a web development bootcamp. I want to stress the word bootcamp here, a bootcamp on my brain. I know sleep deprivation is taking its toll on my mental capacities so far but I was wondering about any specific diets/diet regiments and/or natural supplements I can take to improve my cognitive function.

Answer (score -3):

The results of [this experiment](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1amh2t_bbc-horizon-sugar-v-fat-h264-1280x720-aac-rmac_lifestyle) suggests that you should make sure you get enough carbs. What you should avoid is to eat a low carb, high fat diet.

Comment: You only cite one source, which doesn't have high credibility compared to sites like WHO, .govs, and .edu addresses. This post is in danger of down-votes and even deletion.

Comment: @DaveL But this is not really health related in a positive way, the OP is doing something that is quite unhealthy while the high quality sources focus more on what is healthy. It's a bit like how it was well known among body builders that anabolic steroid work well as performing enhancing drugs  when the  official medical verdict for many decades was that its benefits were unproven. Obviously there was no easy way an official source could come up with a proof as the side effects were well known and as a result you could never get a RCT approved by an ethical committee.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Despite your explanation, the website and video-poster are not reputable. If you want to share it, I suggest including a caveat about your info source in the answer. Additionally, your 2 sentence answer is insufficient; it's not enough to point people to a link. You don't explain why carbs and fat matter, only claiming that they do, and fail to mention any mental benefits. Overall, the answer needs work to meet the site's quality standards, which is why I strongly recommend fixing it before more down-votes come along.